# Customised start and end date of the month

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which contains date and value. I have to compute sum of the values for each month.

`i.e., df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))['Value'].sum()`

But the problem is in my data set starting date of the month is 21 and ending at 20. Is there any way to tell that group the month from 21th day to 20th day to pandas.

Assume my data frame contains starting and ending date is,

```
starting_date=datetime.datetime(2015,11,21)
ending_date=datetime.datetime(2017,11,20)
```

so far i tried,

```
starting_date=df['Date'].min()
ending_date=df['Date'].max()

month_wise_sum=[]
while(starting_date<=ending_date):
    temp=starting_date+datetime.timedelta(days=31)
    e_y=temp.year
    e_m=temp.month
    e_d=20
    temp= datetime.datetime(e_y,e_m,e_d)

    month_wise_sum.append(df[df['Date'].between(starting_date,temp)]['Value'].sum())
    starting_date=temp+datetime.timedelta(days=1)

print month_wise_sum
```

My above code does the thing. but still waiting for pythonic way to achieve it.

My biggest problem is slicing data frame for month wise

for example,

```
2015-11-21 to 2015-12-20
```

Is there any pythonic way to achieve this?
Thanks in Advance.

For Example consider this as my dataframe. It contains date from `date_range(datetime.datetime(2017,01,21),datetime.datetime(2017,10,20))`
Input:

```
          Date     Value
0   2017-01-21 -1.055784
1   2017-01-22  1.643813
2   2017-01-23 -0.865919
3   2017-01-24 -0.126777
4   2017-01-25 -0.530914
5   2017-01-26  0.579418
6   2017-01-27  0.247825
7   2017-01-28 -0.951166
8   2017-01-29  0.063764
9   2017-01-30 -1.960660
10  2017-01-31  1.118236
11  2017-02-01 -0.622514
12  2017-02-02 -1.416240
13  2017-02-03  1.025384
14  2017-02-04  0.448695
15  2017-02-05  1.642983
16  2017-02-06 -1.386413
17  2017-02-07  0.774173
18  2017-02-08 -1.690147
19  2017-02-09 -1.759029
20  2017-02-10  0.345326
21  2017-02-11  0.549472
22  2017-02-12  0.814701
23  2017-02-13  0.983923
24  2017-02-14  0.551617
25  2017-02-15  0.001959
26  2017-02-16 -0.537112
27  2017-02-17  1.251595
28  2017-02-18  1.448950
29  2017-02-19 -0.452310
..         ...       ...
243 2017-09-21  0.791439
244 2017-09-22  1.368647
245 2017-09-23  0.504924
246 2017-09-24  0.214994
247 2017-09-25 -3.020875
248 2017-09-26 -0.440378
249 2017-09-27  1.324862
250 2017-09-28  0.116897
251 2017-09-29 -0.114449
252 2017-09-30 -0.879000
253 2017-10-01  0.088985
254 2017-10-02 -0.849833
255 2017-10-03  1.136802
256 2017-10-04 -0.398931
257 2017-10-05  0.067660
258 2017-10-06  1.080505
259 2017-10-07  0.516830
260 2017-10-08 -0.755461
261 2017-10-09  1.367292
262 2017-10-10  1.444083
263 2017-10-11 -0.840497
264 2017-10-12 -0.090092
265 2017-10-13  0.193068
266 2017-10-14 -0.284673
267 2017-10-15 -1.128397
268 2017-10-16  1.029995
269 2017-10-17 -1.269262
270 2017-10-18  0.320187
271 2017-10-19  0.580825
272 2017-10-20  1.001110

[273 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to slice this dataframe like below

Iter-1:

```
         Date     Value
0  2017-01-21 -1.055784
1  2017-01-22  1.643813
2  2017-01-23 -0.865919
3  2017-01-24 -0.126777
4  2017-01-25 -0.530914
5  2017-01-26  0.579418
6  2017-01-27  0.247825
7  2017-01-28 -0.951166
8  2017-01-29  0.063764
9  2017-01-30 -1.960660
10 2017-01-31  1.118236
11 2017-02-01 -0.622514
12 2017-02-02 -1.416240
13 2017-02-03  1.025384
14 2017-02-04  0.448695
15 2017-02-05  1.642983
16 2017-02-06 -1.386413
17 2017-02-07  0.774173
18 2017-02-08 -1.690147
19 2017-02-09 -1.759029
20 2017-02-10  0.345326
21 2017-02-11  0.549472
22 2017-02-12  0.814701
23 2017-02-13  0.983923
24 2017-02-14  0.551617
25 2017-02-15  0.001959
26 2017-02-16 -0.537112
27 2017-02-17  1.251595
28 2017-02-18  1.448950
29 2017-02-19 -0.452310
30 2017-02-20  0.616847
```

iter-2:

```
         Date     Value
31 2017-02-21  2.356993
32 2017-02-22 -0.265603
33 2017-02-23 -0.651336
34 2017-02-24 -0.952791
35 2017-02-25  0.124278
36 2017-02-26  0.545956
37 2017-02-27  0.671670
38 2017-02-28 -0.836518
39 2017-03-01  1.178424
40 2017-03-02  0.182758
41 2017-03-03 -0.733987
42 2017-03-04  0.112974
43 2017-03-05 -0.357269
44 2017-03-06  1.454310
45 2017-03-07 -1.201187
46 2017-03-08  0.212540
47 2017-03-09  0.082771
48 2017-03-10 -0.906591
49 2017-03-11 -0.931166
50 2017-03-12 -0.391388
51 2017-03-13 -0.893409
52 2017-03-14 -1.852290
53 2017-03-15  0.368390
54 2017-03-16 -1.672943
55 2017-03-17 -0.934288
56 2017-03-18 -0.154785
57 2017-03-19  0.552378
58 2017-03-20  0.096006
```

.

.

.

iter-n:

```
          Date     Value
243 2017-09-21  0.791439
244 2017-09-22  1.368647
245 2017-09-23  0.504924
246 2017-09-24  0.214994
247 2017-09-25 -3.020875
248 2017-09-26 -0.440378
249 2017-09-27  1.324862
250 2017-09-28  0.116897
251 2017-09-29 -0.114449
252 2017-09-30 -0.879000
253 2017-10-01  0.088985
254 2017-10-02 -0.849833
255 2017-10-03  1.136802
256 2017-10-04 -0.398931
257 2017-10-05  0.067660
258 2017-10-06  1.080505
259 2017-10-07  0.516830
260 2017-10-08 -0.755461
261 2017-10-09  1.367292
262 2017-10-10  1.444083
263 2017-10-11 -0.840497
264 2017-10-12 -0.090092
265 2017-10-13  0.193068
266 2017-10-14 -0.284673
267 2017-10-15 -1.128397
268 2017-10-16  1.029995
269 2017-10-17 -1.269262
270 2017-10-18  0.320187
271 2017-10-19  0.580825
272 2017-10-20  1.001110
```

So that i could calculate each month's sum of value series

```
[0.7536957367200978, -4.796100620186059, -1.8423374363366014, 2.3780759926221267, 5.753755441349653, -0.01072884830461407, -0.24877912707664018, 11.666305431020149, 3.0772592888909065]
```

I hope i explained thoroughly.

Comment: Can you post an example of input and desired output?

Comment: @zipa - Added to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the purpose of testing my solution, I generated some random data, frequency is daily but it should work for every frequencies.

```
index = pd.date_range('2015-11-21', '2017-11-20')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data={0: np.random.rand(len(index))})
```

Here you see that I passed as index an array of datetimes. Indexing with dates allow in `pandas` for a lot of added functionalities. With your data you should do (if the `Date` column already only contains datetime values) :

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

Then I would realign artificially your data by substracting 20 days to the index :

```
from datetime import timedelta
df.index -= timedelta(days=20)
```

and then I would resample data to a monthly indexing, summing all data in the same month :

```
df.resample('M').sum()
```

The resulting dataframe is indexed by the last datetime of each month (for me something like :

```
                    0
2015-11-30  3.191098
2015-12-31  16.066213
2016-01-31  16.315388
2016-02-29  13.507774
2016-03-31  15.939567
2016-04-30  17.094247
2016-05-31  15.274829
2016-06-30  13.609203
```

but feel free to reindex it :)

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas.cut() could be a quick solution for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start_date = "2015-11-21"
# As @ALollz mentioned, the month with the original end_date='2017-11-20' was missing.  
# since pd.date_range() only generates dates in the specified range (between start= and end=),
# '2017-11-31'(using freq='M') exceeds the original end='2017-11-20' and thus is cut off.
# the similar situation applies also to start_date (using freq="MS") when start_month might be cut off
# easy fix is just to extend the end_date to a date in the next month or use 
# the end-date of its own month '2017-11-30', or replace end= to periods=25
end_date = "2017-12-20"

# create a testing dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({ "date": pd.date_range(start_date, periods=710, freq='D'), "value": np.random.randn(710)})

# set up bins to include all dates to create expected date ranges
bins = [ d.replace(day=20) for d in pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq="M") ]

# group and summary using the ranges from the above bins
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.date, bins)).sum() 
                              value
date                               
(2015-11-20, 2015-12-20]  -5.222231
(2015-12-20, 2016-01-20]  -4.957852
(2016-01-20, 2016-02-20]  -0.019802
(2016-02-20, 2016-03-20]  -0.304897
(2016-03-20, 2016-04-20]  -7.605129
(2016-04-20, 2016-05-20]   7.317627
(2016-05-20, 2016-06-20]  10.916529
(2016-06-20, 2016-07-20]   1.834234
(2016-07-20, 2016-08-20]  -3.324972
(2016-08-20, 2016-09-20]   7.243810
(2016-09-20, 2016-10-20]   2.745925
(2016-10-20, 2016-11-20]   8.929903
(2016-11-20, 2016-12-20]  -2.450010
(2016-12-20, 2017-01-20]   3.137994
(2017-01-20, 2017-02-20]  -0.796587
(2017-02-20, 2017-03-20]  -4.368718
(2017-03-20, 2017-04-20]  -9.896459
(2017-04-20, 2017-05-20]   2.350651
(2017-05-20, 2017-06-20]  -2.667632
(2017-06-20, 2017-07-20]  -2.319789
(2017-07-20, 2017-08-20]  -9.577919
(2017-08-20, 2017-09-20]   2.962070
(2017-09-20, 2017-10-20]  -2.901864
(2017-10-20, 2017-11-20]   2.873909

# export the result
summary = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.date, bins)).value.sum().tolist()
```

..

Comment: You're wind up missing the last bin from `2017-10-21` to `2017-11-20`. Changing it to `pd.to_datetime(end_date) + MonthEnd(1)` should work

Comment: thanks, I did notice that one, but it's string, no need to convert to datetime format.

Comment: That was just so you could add `MonthEnd(1)` to it within the `date_range`, which you can't do as a string. But there's probably other ways to accomplish it.

Comment: no, it's only an issue from pd.date_range(), not bins